# How to save Linebreak in MS access Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to save some Data with special format. for example:

- **AAAA**
- **BBBB**
- **CCCC**
- **DDDD**

I can save these information in Access but when I want to show them to user. It is shown like this in a textbox:
**AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD**
Whitout any linebreaks.
My question is: How can I save Linebreaks in MS Access DB?

Thank you so much for your helps !

**EDIT 1**

i.e I have this block of information in a .txt file:

```
KENNLINIE KLPRAIL 3
   LANGNAME "Kennlinie zur Umsetzung Raildrucksensorspannung in Raildruck" 
   FUNKTION GGDSKV 
   EINHEIT_X "V"
   EINHEIT_W "MPa"
   ST/X   0.4980468750000000   1.8002319335937500   5.0000000000000000   
   WERT   0.0000000000000000   4.5000000000000000   15.5600000000000000   
END
```

And I want to save **KLPRAIL 3** in one column and

```
 EINHEIT_X "V"
   EINHEIT_W "MPa"
   ST/X   0.4980468750000000   1.8002319335937500   5.0000000000000000   
   WERT   0.0000000000000000   4.5000000000000000   15.5600000000000000
```

in another column

I can do this job with this block of code:

```
Dim kennL As String
Dim kennLS As Boolean
Dim kennLvalue As String
Dim kennLwert As String
Dim keLx As String
Dim keLw As String
Dim kelwer As String


kennL = InStr(1, entireline, "KENNLINIE")
keLx = InStr(1, entireline, "EINHEIT_X")
keLw = InStr(1, entireline, "EINHEIT_W")
keLsx = InStr(1, entireline, "ST/X")
kelwer = InStr(1, entireline, "WERT")
keLend = InStr(1, entireline, "END")

If kennL = 1 Then
kennLvalue = Mid(entireline, 10)
kennLS = True
End If

If keLx = 4 And kennLS = True Then
kennLwert = kennLwert + Mid(entireline, 4) + vbNewLine
End If


If keLw = 4 And kennLS = True Then
kennLwert = kennLwert + Mid(entireline, 4) + vbNewLine
End If

If kennLS = True And (keLsx = 4 Or kelwer = 4) Then
kennLwert = kennLwert + Mid(entireline, 4) + vbNewLine
End If
If kennLS = True And keLend = 1 Then

DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Test_dcml (WertName,WertValue) VALUES ('" & kennLvalue & "','" & kennLwert & "');")
kennLS = False
End If
```

but if I show this Info to user. these information is shown like this:

```
EINHEIT_X "V" EINHEIT_W "MPa" ST/X   0.4980468750000000   1.8002319335937500   5.0000000000000000   WERT   0.0000000000000000   4.5000000000000000   15.5600000000000000
```

**EDIT2**

```
I use this code to show this Information to user:
Dim rcst As Recordset
Set rcst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Test_Wertquery")
rcst.MoveFirst
Text5.SetFocus
Me.Text5.Text = rcst.Fields("WertValue").Value
```

Comment: You can add vbNewLine to do a linebreak but please post your code to make it more clear.

Comment: I did it. I have used vbNewline but it seems that it doesnt work

Comment: "these information is shown like this" how is it shown ? control on a form ? on a report ? textbox ? question is vague

Comment: In a Textbox on a Form. Sorry !

Comment: @Kaja: please provide the code where you show it to the user

Comment: @Belial09: It is accomplished. Thanks

Comment: you do not have an sql statement, you do only select the first entry in the table. Are there old entries before you did change the code (vbnewline)? clear the table and try again. Also,if you put a messagebox before Me.Text5.Text = rcst.Fields("WertValue").Value and show the value, does it contain the linebreaks? Also, if you remove .Text and the SetFocus line it should also work :)

Comment: Yikes. You most definitely do not want to save data with line breaks into a single column. Save the data into separate, dedicated columns and format it *after* you select it for output, not before you store it.

Comment: @Belial09 If I show these Information in Msgbox I can see linebreaks. What do you mean exactly?  what should I do? If I delete the Setfocus, It doesnt work :/

Comment: @Kaja: i will post it as answer so that you can see what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your stored text values display correctly in a `MsgBox`, that means the line breaks are stored correctly in your table.  So the problem is with the text box.

Check the Text Format property on the Data tab of your check box's property sheet.

[image: text box Text Format property]

Change it to *"Plain Text"* if it's not already set as such.  With *"Rich Text"* as the format, line breaks in the box's content will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

```
Dim rcst As DAO.Recordset
Set rcst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Test_Wertquery")

If Not rcst.EOF Then
    rcst.MoveFirst
    Me.Text9 = rcst.Fields("WertValue").Value
    rcst.Close
End If

Set rcst = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem remains :/

Comment: does this change something

Me.Text9 = rcst!WertValue

Comment: im stumped :( VBA does not have a multiline property on textboxes as far as i know. So if you have linebreaks in the messagebox but not in the Textbox. Sorry maybe someone else has a idea.